What determines the value of an asset in a Uniswap v3 pool if ticks in an active tick interval have zero liquidity?
I'm trying to understand by what mechanism the price is in a tick interval, the border ticks of which, as etherscan shows, have zero liquidity?
Data Gathering
The question arose after analyzing the low-liquidity pool v3 "0xcf2b2b81be7614302f55eda8bb50747e4ccb2ca3"
(The pool was chosen from several similar "garbage" pools that have low liquidity and low activity, and the traded assets in these pools are marked with a Warning sign).
At the time of writing the question, the pool liquidity was 2996780299407601196, and the tick value was -377684.
(I hope these values ​​will remain relevant for some time).
Based on the tick_spacing = 200 parameter, we get the tick interval to which the current tick belongs: tick_min = -377800, tick_max = -377600.
If you look at the information about ticks -377800 and -377600, you can see that there is no liquidity there (liquidityGross: 0, liquidityNet: 0).
I have always assumed that the current price of an asset is directly related to the current minimum tick in the tick interval, in this case it is tick -377800, in which the liquidityGross and liquidityNet values should have a non-zero value.
It is also worth noting that the swap forecast in the Uniswap app for this asset behaves quite adequately and does not "falls", for example, with an asset quote value of $ 1000. That is, everything looks as if Uniswap "finds" liquidity.
Question:
By what mechanism is the price in the tick interval, which, as Etherscan shows, have zero liquidity?
Perhaps this state of the pool is due to the fact that liquidity was withdrawn and the pool has states of general liquidity + all parameters related to the current state of the asset: sqrtPriceX96, tick (slot0 method) based on the "external" market situation and may not be directly related to the calculation of the internal parameters of the pool?

Each position in a Uniswap v3 pool has a fixed liquidity depth, unaffected by external factors, only changed when the position itself is modified.
The active liquidity in a pool is the sum of the liquidity from all active (in-range) positions in that pool.
For example, if there is a position from tick -400000 to tick -200000, the active liquidity in the pool will include the liquidity of that position. It doesn't necessarily mean that the ticks -377800 or -377600 will have non-zero liquidityGross or liquidityNet values. Only the ticks that are the endpoints of some position are initialized and have nonzero values of these parameters.
